# Eclipse shows less lines in linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, vmware, eclipse-mars

When I use Eclipse in *windows* it shows approximately **100** lines when editor in full screen, But In *linux* in shows approximately **50**. Font size is bigger in linux so it shows less lines. I checked screen resolution it is same in windows and linux. When I increase resolution in linux Eclipse start showing more lines in editor, but *VMWare* starts showing scroll bars to access the whole screen. How to show more lines in Eclipse in linux or how to remove scroll bars from *VMWare* when resolution is increased?

Answer (score 1):

Window > Preference > General > Editors > Text Editors > 'Colors and Fonts'

Select `Basic` and `Text Font`, you can edit the font size here for all editors

[image]

---

Also note that the number of lines you see on different platforms doesn't strictly depend only on eclipse configuration, but also on the area of window that eclipse has on each platform. Probably you are using some docker or there is a panel on linux desktop environment which takes too much space and at the end eclipse window gets less space than on windows thats why the number of lines in editor is less than on windows

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I change size to `6` for font It shows approximately `100` lines in editor but It makes font size too small.

Comment: Check what is the font size on your windows host and set the same size on linux version of eclipse. And you are sure that the desktop resolutions are the same on both platforms, right ?

Comment: Font size in windows is `10` and I again checked resolution is same both side `1280X1024`.

Comment: 1. Restart eclipse 2. Check if your editor is not zoomed in, try to zoom out with Ctrl -

Comment: I tried Ctrl and - to zoom out, But noting happened. It was not even zooming up with Ctrl and +.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91099/discussion-between-deimus-and-varun).